# How to chain functions in CNTK/C++

Tags: c++, cntk

I want to use the output of one CNTK function as the input to another in c++/cntk. i.e. I have two CNTK::FunctionPtr instances:

fn1 - input called 'features', output called 'intermediate'
fn2 - input called 'intermediate', output called 'op'

The minibatch source provides 'features'. How do I tell CNTK that the output of fn1 should be the input of function2. In python this is easy as you just define a function:

output = fn2(fn1(features))

.. and use thiswith a trainer.

How do you do this in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: You can "chain" function calls just the same in C++. If you want to pass the result of the call `fn1()` to the function `fn2` then just do `fn2(fn1())`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, but did you read the question properly? These are not C/C++ functions, they are CNTK::FunctionPtr instances from the CNTK library.

Comment: BTW the context is f2 is a function (CNTK:FunctionPtr) loaded from disk, whereas f1 is initilised in code. f1 is a pre-processing network that varies depending on the data type, which is why the need for this.